# php mail() function code sends email once to a particular email address

Tags: php, email

Simple php mail() function code in order to test the mailer on my website, but it only sent the message once, please what did I do wrong?

```
<?php
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "info@companyemail.com";
    $to = "mypersonal@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Checking PHP mail";
    $message = "The PHP mail works just fine you should see it in your inbox";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    echo "The email message was sent.";
?>
```

Comment: How many times you expected it to mail?

Comment: This code looks like it will send mail only once, if you want to send more than one times then you need to write mail function into `loop`.

Comment: Aravind Bhat K I want it to send to a particular email many times

Comment: saddam thanks I'll check it, so it will send to a particular email many times?

Comment: @saddam how do i use loop do I use while () loop?

Comment: `while` and `for` both are good, but you can use `while` to send mail at least once.

Comment: so how do I write it?

Comment: @saddam this is what I did

Comment: <?php
while () {
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "info@severnfundingninvestment.com";
    $to = "ogukingsley@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Checking PHP mail";
    $message = "The PHP mail works just fine you should see it in your inbox";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    echo "The email message was sent.";
}
?>

Comment: you forgot the condition in while loop, follow the given code I'm attaching below.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to add conditions in `while` loop, go through this below code.

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10) //provide as many as mail are you sending,like it will sends 10 times.
{ 
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "info@severnfundingninvestment.com";
    $to = "ogukingsley@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Checking PHP mail";
    $message = "The PHP mail works just fine you should see it in your inbox";
    $headers = "From:" . $from; mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    echo "The email message was sent.";
    $i = $i + 1;
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks, I actually want the code to send email to user anytime the user logs in, how can I echo a user's email from a session? @saddam

Comment: you need to write `session_start();` at top of the `php` page then to access `session` value write code like `$_SESSION["session_name"]`.

Comment: thank you saddam, but what if I want the email to send each time the user logs in and you used while ($i < 10) //provide as many as mail are you sending,like it will sends 10 times. that means it will only send ten times? please explain thank you

Comment: what do you want  to do actually? do you want send mail as user logged in or something else?

Comment: I want to send mail immediately users login that is anytime they log in the code you sent me just loops the echo "The email message has been sent" 10 times

Comment: I want to send mail immediately users login that is anytime they log in the code you sent me just loops the echo "The email message has been sent" 10 times

Comment: You can write your `mail()` when user's session created at the time of login.

Comment: I don't understand